# Force traffic through Azure loadbalancer

Tags: azure

I am using resource manager and have a vm created I also have an internet facing loadbalancer, I have created nat rule for the loadbalancer and configured the network security group for the VM, but it is now possible to access the port on both the loadbalancer and the virtual machines external IP address how do I only allow traffic that has come from the loadbalancer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple options:

a. Remove the VM's Public IP address

In this case you can still access the VM through VPN directly if needed.

b. <strike>Add a rule to the NSG that blocks all traffic that does not come from a load balancer</strike>

Sorry, seems like I misunderstood what the AZURE_LOADBALANCER tag does. As you said, it only works with health probes, as any traffic coming through the load balancer looks identical.

I was thinking maybe you could get by with having 2 NICs, one with public IP that you use, and one with no public IP connected to load balancer. But before you try that, you should know it won't work. Only primary NICs can have a public IP, and only primary NICs can be connected to load balancers.

It would be easiest just to remove the public IP address on the NIC and use point-to-site VPN to connect.

Comment: I would like to use the load balancer tag option, but the tag azureloadbalancer appears to be only for the load balancer probs not traffic, do you know a way of getting the network security group to accept only load balancer traffic?

Comment: Sorry about that, I misunderstood the tag's meaning :) I edited my post accordingly.